# Eclipse doesn't allow to form string which is regular expression

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

Trying to assign as String variable the regular expression but Eclipse IDE doen't allowing to do that. Why?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use "`\\s`" instead. This is because `\s` isn't a `String` escape, rather it is used in the regex. Java will see your string and change the `\\` into a single `\` (as `\\` is a `\` escaped). You will also have to do this for all of the other escapes (like `pattern = "(\\s)*(\\w\\w(\\w)*)...`)

To make this more understandable, you know how you can put quotes in a `String` (like `String s = "He said, \"Wow.\"";`)? Well, you can put backslashes in a `String` by escaping them like `\\`. Then it will send those backslashes to the regex functions/classes, which will then understand them.